# Create a section in UITableView like in 'Music' app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

How do you create a section of UITableView with numbers for each row like numbers 1, 2, 3 for each track in 'Music' app in iOS? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `UITableViewCell` and create a subview UIlabel property, say..`trackNumber` and in your `cellForRowAtIndex..` method you initialize your custom cell.

EDIT: Added example

```
   //CustomCell.h
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *trackNumber;

@end

//CustomCell.m
@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize trackNumber;

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
            self.trackNumber = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,40,40)] autorelease];
            [self addSubview:self.trackNumber];
        }
        return self;
    }


    @end
```

To use it `#import "CustomCell.h"` and in your implementation.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

cell.trackNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[indexPath row]];

// Configure the cell.
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `UITableViewCell` and do whatever you want with it.  In the inspector change the cell style to Custom.  Then draw in whatever you want.  Make sure that you use the tag property on the view section of the new labels and other elements you create in the cell, because you will need those tags to access any custom labels, buttons, textfields, whatever that you make in the cell.  Basically in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function you can pull apart your custom cell using stuff like

```
UILabel *numberLabel = (UILabel *)[customCell viewWithTag:1];
```